# Android production Google and Facebook signing not working

Tags: android, flutter, facebook-login, google-signin

my app just got publish a few hours ago in the play store, facing my first problem is that Facebook and Google sign in not working for some reason!!

I'm using flutter, the issue was there ( before I publish to the store ) when I installed the app with `--release` tag on my device using the command line `flutter run --release` and I solved by generating `SHA-1` for the releasing key for Google and Facebook and everything worked.

But the issue now back when I get to install the app from the play store!!

The commands I used in [here](https://medium.com/@akashmahali/facebook-login-google-sign-in-not-working-on-android-app-in-production-5febd9537f92): I tried again but it gives me the same keys already I have add on the Facebook developer console and googles firebase settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it turns out that google signed a new certificate for me ‍♂️ and need to take/use that one (fingerprint) and use it with any required API.